# How to make intervals in cycle iterations

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I want my cycle to execute each iteration with an interval in one (two/n) second. How can I do it? I tried to use `sleep (5)` but i think it is wrong decision.

I thought about timer^ but i thing it's wrong idea too

```
self.syncTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(serverSync)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
```

and selector

```
-(void) serverSync {
 NSLog (@"Hello");
}
```

In that case i will have Hello every 5 seconds.

And i need

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array.count; i ++) {
   NSLog (@"Hello - %d", i);
   some code;
}
```

And it must look as

- 00.00 Hello - 0
- 00.05 Hello - 1
- 00.10 Hello - 2

Comment: What's wrong with the `NSTimer` solution ?

Comment: how is the array involved with the timer?

Comment: Why you don't want use the ``NSTimer`` and a static variable to know the increment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
int count;

self.syncTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(nextHello)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];

-(void)nextHello {
   if (count < 999) {
      NSLog (@"Hello - %d", count);
      some code;
      count++;
   } else {
      [self.syncTimer invalidate]; //Stop Timer
   }
}
```

Or if you don't want to use NSTimer you can use `performSelector` `afterDelay`. Like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(nextHello:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]; //Start the Cycle somewhere

-(void)nextHello:(NSNumber*)count {
   NSLog (@"Hello - %@", count);
   Some Code
   [self performSelector:@selector(nextHello:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[count intValue]+1] afterDelay:5.0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you delay time in C:

```
#include <STDIO.H>
#include <TIME.H>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%i\n",i); // Write the current 'countdown' number
        sleep(1); // Wait a second
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use something like this (but it not so clear as using NSTimer)

```
- (void)sayHello {
    __block NSInteger iteration = 0;
    [self execute:^{
        NSLog(@"Hello: %d", iteration);
        iteration++;
    }
        withCount:5
            delay:0.2];
}

- (void)execute:(void(^)(void))executor repeatCount:(NSInteger)count delay:(NSTimeInterval)delayInSeconds{
    if (count == 0) {
        return;
    };

    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        executor();
        [self execute:executor withCount:count - 1 delay:delayInSeconds];
    });
}
```